# position fixed at a given height

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollview, css-position

I have been trying to put an element to fixed position within a given scroll height with Javascript. Outside of this height range, the position should be back to relative.

Here is what I have done so far. The `position:fixed` is inside the `about-option` class. When it gets to 4680, the class is added.

How do I make it have a height end-point of 5800 i.e 4680 - 5800, and also remove the class outside this height range?

```
window.onscroll = function () {
        myFunction();
      };

      function myFunction() {
        if (
          document.documentElement.scrollTop > 4680 ||
          document.body.scrollTop > 4680
        ) {
          document.getElementById("about-txt").classList.add("about-option");
        } else {
          document.getElementById("about-text").className = "";
        }
      }
```

css

```
.about-option {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  width: 40%;
  right: 7%;
```

Comment: And how it went?

Comment: the class is added at or greater than 4680, which in  turn changes the position to fixed. but the class remains fixed and does not return to the normal position even when less than 4680, unless the page is reloaded.

Comment: You have a typo. `about-text` -> `about-txt`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to do what position sticky does: once the element hits the window's top boundery it starts sticking and if you scroll to the inverse way, it goes back to move together with content. Like here:

https://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/QYLEdK

```
<main class="main-container">
  <header class="main-header">HEADER</header>
  <div class="main-content">MAIN CONTENT</div>
  <footer class="main-footer">FOOTER</footer>
</main>
```

```
body{color:#fff; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:40px; }
.main-container{ max-width:600px; margin:0 auto; border:solid 10px green; padding:10px; margin-top:40px;}
.main-container *{padding:10px;background:#aaa; border:dashed 5px #000;}
.main-container * + *{margin-top:20px;}
.main-header{
  height:50px; background:#aaa; border-color:red;
}
.main-content{
  min-height:1000px;
}

.main-header{position:-webkit-sticky; position:sticky; top:0;}
```

The trick part is to remember to add a container outside the sticky element, otherwise, it will not work.

I hope it helps!